# Hidden <ul> vanishes while hovering between <li> to it

Tags: html, css

Below I have a hidden `<ul>` which appears when the `<li>` 'More' is hovered over.

Due to the margin of the `<li>`, the `<ul>` dissapears when hovering between 'Extras' and the `<ul>` - how do I prevent this from happening?

```css
#container ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#container li {
  color: #fff;
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: black;
}
#container li a {
  display: block;
}
.extras:hover > ul.hidden {
  display: block;
}
ul.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="center" style="text-align: center; display: inline-block;">
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li>Example 1</li>
        <li>Example 2</li>
        <li class="extras">More
          <ul class="hidden">
            <li>Hoverable</li>
            <li>Hoverable</li>
            <li>Hoverable</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Example 3</li>
        <li>Example 4</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ul` tag is not getting height. Here try this

```css
#container ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}
#container li {
  color: #fff;
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: black;
}
#container li a {
  display: block;
}
.extras:hover > ul.hidden {
  display: block;
}
ul.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="center" style="text-align: center; display: inline-block;">
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li>Example 1</li>
        <li>Example 2</li>
        <li class="extras">More
          <ul class="hidden">
            <li>Hoverable</li>
            <li>Hoverable</li>
            <li>Hoverable</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Example 3</li>
        <li>Example 4</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! By the way, I was able to use your code without adding `width: 100%;` to the `ul` style :)

Answer (score 0):

Where you use `float` always remember to set layout of parent.

```css
#container .center {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
}

#container ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#container .nav:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}

#container .nav > li {
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}

#container ul li {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 60px;
  background: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 80px;
}

#container ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

#container ul ul li {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#container ul li a {
  display: block;
}
.extras:hover > ul.hidden {
  display: block;
}
ul.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="center">
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li>Example 1</li>
        <li>Example 2</li>
        <li class="extras">More
          <ul class="hidden">
            <li>Hoverable</li>
            <li>Hoverable</li>
            <li>Hoverable</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Example 3</li>
        <li>Example 4</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```